# How to use LCP and suffix array to find the maximum number of occurrences of a given pattern in a string?

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem on how to search for a given pattern in a string using LCP and suffix array, but I am not able to solve the part on how I can find the number occurrences of that pattern.

I have tried to do a binary search on possible occurrences but I'm not able to find how to update current number of occurrence.

Comment: If you know how to find one occurence in suffix array, then you can find first and last occurencies. Then all pattern occurencies lie exactly between those two.

Comment: With LCP, you should just be able to count how many entries share the common prefix (or match the pattern, if you are using something more complicated than just a direct prefix comparison).  Based on the question, I don't understand how a binary search could possibly help, so maybe you should provide examples of what you are trying to do, as well as code that shows your approach so far.

Comment: Thanks , Mike Koltsov Matt Jordan , I have solved the problem . For a given pattern , you need to find its first occurrence , if you able to find its first occurrence then you can find the maximum number of occurrences of that particular pattern as in suffix array all the suffixes with initial prefixes as pattern must be consecutive. To find  occurrence of that pattern binary search can help as suffix array is a sorted array of strings in lexicographical order.